# How to transfer (to connect) data between Digital Micrograph and R

Tags: r, dm-script

I'm a new DM's user and I need to transfer data (pixels bright) between **Digital Micrograph** and **R**, for processing and modelling an image.

Specifically, I would need to extract the bright pixels from an original image, send it to **R** for processing, and return to DM for to represent the new image.

I would like to know if it is possible and how to do it from an script in DM.

A lot of thanks. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very little *direct* connection between DM (scripting) and the *outside world*, so the best solution is quite likely the following (DM-centric) route:

A script is started in DM, which does:

- all the UI needed
- extract the intensities etc.
- save all required data in a suitable format on disc at specific path. (Raw data/text-data/...)
- call an external application ( anything you can call from a command prompt, including .bat files) and waits until that command has finished

Have all your R code been written in a way that it can be called from a command prompt, potentially with command prompt parameters (i.e. a configuration file):

- read data from specific  path
- process as required  (without an UI, so do it 'silently')
- save results on disc on specific path
- close application

At this point, the script in DM continues, reading in the results (and potentially doing some clean-up of files on disc.)

---

So, in essence, the important thing is that your R-code can work as a "stand-alone" black-box executable fully controlled by command-line parameters.

The command you will need to launch an external application can be found in the help-documentation under "Utility Functions" and is `LaunchExternalProcess`.  It has been introduced with GMS 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want try using the commands `ScrapCopy()` and `ScrapPasteNew()`to copy an image (or image subarea) into the clipboard, but I am not sure how the data is handled there exactly.